# Was the Argo sentient and capable of conversation, or was its speech more like Siri or the USS Enterprise computer?

Tags: greek, magic, argonauts

The Argo was built with a branch from the Dodona oak which, according to numerous sources, could speak.

I’m wondering about the nature of this ability: did this “speech” make the Argo a fully developed character with opinions and desires of its own, or was it more like the magical equivalent of Siri, a voice-interface only capable of limited statements, answers to specific questions, and occasional prophecies?

Comment: It was mostly prophecy, The USS Enterprise had a computer capable of much more than the Dodona plank/branch. Interesting question though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say Argo was not self aware. Instead, Zeus “... *spoke through the wood taken from one of his Dodonian oaks, as stated in the first book of the Argonautica (Apollonius of Rhodes, 2009), when a talking beam that Athena had made from a Dodonian oak and fitted in the middle of Argo’s keel, spoke with a terrible voice that frightened the Argonauts.*”  - [Oracle Trees in the Ancient Hellenic World](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41761723)

Comment: Your link goes to nothing but a couple of "access denied" tags.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s now only available behind a paywall. I’ve supplied a link to that…